# Highlighting only the geometry of a parent object in autodesk's online viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have revit model in which a parent element has both children and its own geometry. In the online viewer it is possible to select the parent through clicking the respective geometry, in which case only the geometry for the parent is highlighted. ([selected through a click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YEPO.png))

If I select the element through the tree the whole model gets highlighted.
([selected through the model browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guBt2.png))

In our web application, we are unable to get the former behavior. When passing the dbId of the parent to viewer.select, the parent plus all the children get highlighted. Same happens when we click the parent element's geometry. **How can we select only the parent object programmatically?**

We have tried passing different selection modes (overlayed, regular, mixed) to viewer.select but that didn't help and all objects got selected regardless of that parameter.

- In this question it is mentioned by autodesk staff that only leaf nodes have geometries. That doesn't seem to be the case here:
  [Determine if node is an assembly or part in viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931337/determine-if-node-is-an-assembly-or-part-in-viewer)

Comment: what's the file format? would you be able to share a non-confidential sample file? Or the access token endpoint to test your URN? If so, please email to forge.help at autodesk.com

Comment: did you try the suggested steps?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the sample file. I did the following: open the model, select manually and, via console, typed `.getSelection()`, which returns me the **dbId** of the selected element. Now unselect everything. Then run `.select(2890)` and the result is as expected: only the top element is selected (as shown in the image below). I'm using `Viewer 3.3`.

You can try my sample [live here](https://forgedatamanagement.apphb.com/), it uses the [Basic Application](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-application/) tutorial.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Augusto, I updated our viewer version to [3.3]("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=3.3.*"), however I still see the same behavior. Is there a setting on the viewer for this?
We are not using BIM 360, so I couldn't try the sample app.

Comment: is the same Viewer, you can also try it at modelderivative.apphb.com (same results). can you clarify which methods you use?